# How to create an preferences window similar to VLC with Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget, overlap, qt-designer

I want to create an preferences window somehow similar to VLC. For that purpose I added a `QTreeWidget` for selecting the different preferences. I want to group the `QWidgets`, which belong together, in a parent `QWidget` so I can hide them all at once. I think that is the right way? My problem now it that the `Qt Designer` does not give the posibillity to hide widgets. What would be the best way to create multiple overlapping widgets, so someone can click on an item in the `QTreeWidget`, and only the relevant widgets are shown?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#details

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for your answer but I wanted to avoid QTabWidget since that would not look very good with a lot of tabs. But I found `QStackedWidget` which exactly fulfills my requirements.

Comment: `QTabWidget` is matching better settings in VLC. You have to just tweak visualization of tabs, that is it. With `QStackedWidget` you will simply implement functionality already done in `QTabWidget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i found that `QStackedWidget` exactly fullfils my requirements :)